# Jest: test if callback function from addEventListener was called

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have next functions:

```js
const hashChangeCallback = event => {
   console.log('event', event.oldUrl)
}

const hashHandler = () => {
  return {
    add: () => {
      window.addEventListener('hashchange', (event) => hashChangeCallback(event), false)
    },
    remove: () => {
      window.removeEventListener('hashchange', (event) => hashChangeCallback(event), false)
    },
  }
}
```

In my Jest test, I want to check, if `hashChangeCallback` function was called when event was triggered:

```js
import { hashHandler } from './urlHashChangeListener'

describe('urlHashChangeListener', () => {
  const setupHashListeners = hashHandler()


  it('hashChangeCallback should be called when hash changed if listener is added', () => {
    setupHashListeners.add()

    window.dispatchEvent(new HashChangeEvent('hashchange', {
      oldURL: 'http://test.com/test.html#hash123', 
      newURL: 'http://test.com/test.html#hash3'
    }))

    // expect hashChangeCallback to be called
  })
})
```

How to do it properly? Do I have to mock/spy on this function somehow?

Comment: Not possible without mocking addEventListener. hashChangeCallback is local so it cannot be reached in tests. Doesn't make sense in a case that you posted. Just test that console.log was called.

Answer (score 0):

If the `hashChangeCallback` function is not exported, you can't mock or spy it. You can indirectly assert whether `hashChangeCallback` is called by asserting whether `console.log` is called.

Besides, it should be `event.oldURL` rather than `event.oldUrl`.

E.g.

`urlHashChangeListener.ts`:

```
const hashChangeCallback = (event) => {
  console.log('event', event.oldURL);
};

export const hashHandler = () => {
  return {
    add: () => {
      window.addEventListener('hashchange', (event) => hashChangeCallback(event), false);
    },
    remove: () => {
      window.removeEventListener('hashchange', (event) => hashChangeCallback(event), false);
    },
  };
};
```

`urlHashChangeListener.test.ts`:

```
import { hashHandler } from './urlHashChangeListener';

describe('urlHashChangeListener', () => {
  const setupHashListeners = hashHandler();

  it('hashChangeCallback should be called when hash changed if listener is added', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    setupHashListeners.add();

    window.dispatchEvent(
      new HashChangeEvent('hashchange', {
        oldURL: 'http://test.com/test.html#hash123',
        newURL: 'http://test.com/test.html#hash3',
      })
    );

    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('event', 'http://test.com/test.html#hash123');
    logSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/63613274/urlHashChangeListener.test.ts (7.068 s)
  urlHashChangeListener
    ✓ hashChangeCallback should be called when hash changed if listener is added (17 ms)

  console.log
    event http://test.com/test.html#hash123

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.745 s, estimated 8 s
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generalise your functions to make your testing a little easier and reduce duplication:

```js
const controlListener = event => fn => ({
    add: () => window.addEventListener(event, fn, false),
    remove: () => window.removeEventListener(event, fn, false),
  })

export const hashListener = controlListener('hashchange')

// In your production code
const hashHandler = hashListener(hashChangeCallback)

// In your test file
const mockHashChangeCallback = jest.fn()
const hashHandler = hashListener(mockHashChangeCallback)
expect(mockHashChangeCallback.mock.calls).toEqual([...])
```